# Head-First Python 2nd edition template external links won't load. (The connection was reset)

Tags: python, css, static, connection

I'm currently self-teaching myself Python using a book called "Head First: Python (2nd Edition)" I am creating my first web app and it is asking for me to download .html and .css code templates from https://python.itcarlow.ie/ed2/. The site will not load and says "This site can't be reached, The connection was reset" [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kfk5z.png)

Here is a list of troubleshooting steps I tried but still no luck:

1. Checked that other websites are working (All other sites work)
2. checked on laptop, desktop, and phone (website still doesn't load)
3. Tried different browsers (chrome, edge, ie)
4. check the proxy settings
5. clear the browser cache
6. reset/restart the router
7. temporarily disable the firewall and antivirus programs
8. contacted internet provider

I wish there was someone familiar with this section in the book who can just give me the files.

Not sure if I am missing anything.
Can someone please help?

Comment: The site can't be reached. Please note that this question is actually *not* a programming question, so it's off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Thierry pointed out, this is not actually a programming question.
First thing to do when a website fails loading in python (or any other language/browser/potato) is to try in a different way. (Note that I know you've tried some of these, but the last one is very important)

1. Try different way (eg browser>curl>ping)
2. Try different machine (eg. pc>mobile)
3. Try different internet connection (fixed>mobile)

Easiest is to try all in at the same time (eg use your browser on your mobile while using the mobile internet connection).

There are also sites that can check if another website is working or not. This would also do what I listed out above.

All that being said, the website itself is down.

Doing some quick googling for *Head First: Python (2nd Edition) files* I found a github repo that contains all the files you need for the (very excellent) book.

You can find it [here](https://github.com/drjkuria/head-first-python-2ed)...

Comment: Awesome thank you. This is my first time using any forum my apologies I'm a newbie at this but I do greatly appreciate the feedback. I'm learning everyday